# i am getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' for my simple GUI program in python

Tags: python, tkinter, get, attributes, nonetype

I am getting an attribute error for any function inside the ButtonClick method. please help in rectifying this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

enter = tk.Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx =10 , pady = 10)

def ButtonClick(number):

    print(number)
    current = enter.get()
    print(current)
    # enter.delete(0,END)
    # enter.insert(0, current + number)


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", bg="yellow",padx = 40, pady= 20, command=lambda: ButtonClick(1)).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback or do we guess?

Comment: What does the `grid()` method return?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `enter` is `None` because that's what the `.grid` method returns. Instead of trying to use it immediately, move it to `entry.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python shell makes it easy to experiment. Assuming the error is with `enter` I just pasted the first part of your code into the shell.

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> 
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> 
>>> enter = tk.Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx =10 , pady = 10)
>>> repr(enter)
'None'
```

Yep, its `None`. And that's typical. Object methods often don't return their own object. Its convenient for method chaining, but most objects are not designed for that. Just do what examples and tutorials show and put it on a separate line.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

enter = tk.Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
enter.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx =10 , pady = 10)

def ButtonClick(number):

    print(number)
    current = enter.get()
    print(current)
    # enter.delete(0,END)
    # enter.insert(0, current + number)


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", bg="yellow",padx = 40, pady= 20, command=lambda: ButtonClick(1)).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```